# Send the value of the controller to the validator in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

Is there a way to send value from the controller to the validator?

This is from my controller trying to send a value to the validator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Adjectives;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\AdjectiveRequest;
use App\Models\IucnNumber;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IucnNumberController extends Controller
{
    
    public function store(){
        $request = AdjectiveRequest::rules("App\Models\IucnNumber");
}
```

This is a validation that tries to get value:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AdjectiveRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules($model)
    {
        $classNumber = $model::all();

        return [
            'name' =>  "max:60|string|not_in:".collect($classNumber)->implode('name', ','),
        ];
    }

    
}
```

But this method is incorrect

How can I send the value to the validator?

Comment: Waht do you want to validate in this code?
FormRequest generally used to validate the form request fields

Comment: Start with [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation). They explain that Form Requests (like you are using) are intended to run before you even reach the controller code.  But they're just classes, you can write code in them other than just validation rules/msgs. You have access to the current request there.

Comment: I want to pass the model name from the controller to the validator.

 For example, I have a variable called "$ model" in my controller ... I'm going to pass this variable to the validator to use when checking the form

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is that a form request filters values until it reaches the controller, for this put it into the action parameter:

```
   public function store(AdjectiveRequest $request){
```

I think it is better and more correct to define a few form requests for different models you need. If you want to do more unique validators you can check route name, middleware and etc inside of the request.

I don't recommend doing it in that way (because controller actions should be as thin as possible), but if you still want to do validation inside of the action (in your case) you don't need to make a separate form request but do smth like here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic, so you define rules directly in the form reuqest

Comment: That means I have to put a validator for each model?